# Whats wrong with the SQL Syntax?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, jpql

Hey guys I've got a Problem with a JPA Query.

Here the Code-Snippet:

```
TypedQuery<ViVertragDl> q = entityManager.createQuery("select * from ViVertragDl c where c.id = " + editContract.getId(), ViVertragDl.class);
List<ViVertragDl> jpaContractDls = q.getResultList();
```

And the Glassfish Log throws this Error, after testing in SOAP-UI:

```
    Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [select * from ViVertragDl c where c.id = 51]. 
[28, 28] A select statement must have a FROM clause.
[7, 7] The left expression is missing from the arithmetic expression.
[9, 27] The right expression is not an arithmetic expression.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.buildException(HermesParser.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.validate(HermesParser.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.populateQueryImp(HermesParser.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.buildQuery(HermesParser.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.<init>(EJBQueryImpl.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.<init>(EJBQueryImpl.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1603)
    ... 91 more
```

It Just says "A select statement must have a FROM Clause.", but in my opinion there is one.

Comment: Okay, fixed it by myself. There should be "c" instead of " * " Wildmarks seem not to work in JPQL

Comment: "Seems not to work" ? JPQL has a defined SYNTAX. It isn't guesswork. www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_2/jpa/jpql.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should try:

```
select c from ViVertragDl c where c.id = " + editContract.getId()
```

http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/select

Comment: Thanks have fixed it like a minute before.

Comment: @patrick I look at objectdb with respect, seems very interesting environment. Do You think experiences from this integrated objectDB +JPA implementation can be extended to "classic" JPA environments? Do You use objectdb in heavy real world projects?

Comment: @Jacek Cz Actually I am still a student and use the website as a reference for correct using the Java Persistence API.

Comment: @Patrick OK, oodbd seems very good at design and educational level.  Few times I had reflection to use it commercially but licence (unfriendly to business to some degree) and no information about hard use stop this project.

Comment: @Patrick. Few days ago: You are right working with objectdb documentation. It is good designed, very nice formatted (and high in google). I use too (in general sense - when have errors go to specific provider i.e. Eclipse)